# How to set the user as logged in on firebase.auth(node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I have an app using sign in with a custom token, written on webpack observes. What I want to  do now is mark the user after successful login by custom token  as logged on firebase auth and firebase firestore, where I have the collections with users, and document for each user with data and some uid. I don't know how to to that.

Here is my code:

```
generateToken(uid) {   
const uid = 'some-uid';
this.trigger(this.signals.action.onGenerateToken);
firebase.admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
.then((customToken) => {
  console.log(customToken);
})
.catch(function (error){
  if (error.Code === 'auth/invalid-custom-token') {
    alert('The token you provided is not valid.');
  }
  else {
  this.trigger(this.signals.error.onGenerateToken);
  }
})
 }

login(uid) {
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)
.then(function() {
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser; 
  if (user) {
    //mark the user as active (logged) after successful login on firebase auth and firebase firestore 
   };
  this.trigger(this.signals.success.onLogin);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  if (errorCode === 'auth/too-many-requests') {
    this.trigger(this.signals.error.tooManyRequests);
  }
  else {
      this.trigger(this.signals.error.userDisabled);
  }
  });
  }
```

Comment: Does this code generates any error?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, first create a reference to your user document, then call `update()` on the reference and pass in an object containing the properties you want to update and their new values.

```
let userRef = firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId);
userRef.update({active:true});
```

Check the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) for more info on how to read and write to firebase.